# Use of the Eisenstein Criterion

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I am looking at the Eisenstein criterion and this works for unique factorization domain. Now I am asking myself if $\Bbb Q$ is a unique factorization domain? I would yes because it is a field. Now why we use often the criterion to $\Bbb Z$ and conclude with the Gauss lemma that it is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ instead using it directly to $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is a UFD, but it has no prime elements as it is a field, so the Eisenstein criterion isn't really useful to apply there directly.

Comment: Ah it has no prime element because every element has an inverse (of course except 0), right?

Comment: Yes, that is the reason.